# Does aqueous KOH favor SN2 or SN1 with secondary halides?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution

I have read that aq. KOH is *equally reactive* towards SN1 and SN2 with secondary halides. I'm aware that aq. KOH will participate in SN2 as well because of the lack of steric hindrance in secondary halides, but since aq. KOH is a polar protic solvent, shouldn't it *favor* SN1 comparatively?

Comment: I would expect a base as strong as hydroxide ion to favor SN2, as it would probably be strongly "attracted" to a carbocation while the latter is forming.